# Still getting duplicate token error after calling DuplicateTokenEx for impersonated token

Tags: c#, impersonation

I'm trying to return a `Sytem.IntPtr` from a service call so that the client can use impersonation to call some code. My imersonation code works properly if not passing the token back from a WCF service. I'm not sure why this is not working. I get the following error:

> "Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated."

Here is my code that *does* work except when I try to pass the token back from a service to a WinForm C# client to then impersonate.

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
public extern static bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, int TokenType, int ImpersonationLevel, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

private IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
private IntPtr dupeTokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int Length;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}



public enum SecurityImpersonationLevel
{
    SecurityAnonymous = 0,
    SecurityIdentification = 1,
    SecurityImpersonation = 2,
    SecurityDelegation = 3
}

public enum TokenType
{
    TokenPrimary = 1,
    TokenImpersonation = 2
}

private const int MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;


[PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public System.IntPtr GetWindowsUserToken(string UserName, string Password, string DomainName)
{

    IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
    IntPtr dupTokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);

    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    //This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

    //Initialize the token handle            
    tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

    //Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token for credentials supplied.
    bool returnValue = LogonUser(UserName, DomainName, Password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref tokenHandle);        

    //Make sure a token was returned; if no populate the ResultCode and throw an exception:
    int ResultCode = 0;
    if (false == returnValue)
    {
        ResultCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ResultCode, "API call to LogonUser failed with error code : " + ResultCode);
    }

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    sa.bInheritHandle = true;
    sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = (IntPtr)0;


    bool dupReturnValue = DuplicateTokenEx(tokenHandle, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, ref sa, (int)SecurityImpersonationLevel.SecurityDelegation, (int)TokenType.TokenImpersonation, ref dupTokenHandle);

    int ResultCodeDup = 0;
    if (false == dupReturnValue)
    {
        ResultCodeDup = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ResultCode, "API call to DuplicateToken failed with error code : " + ResultCode);
    }

    //Return the user token
    return dupTokenHandle;

}
```

Any idea if I'm not using the call to `DuplicateTokenEx` correctly? According to the MSDN documentation I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I should be able to create a token valid for delegation and use across the context on remote systems. When 'SecurityDelegation' is used, the server process can impersonate the client's security context on remote systems.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: No and I don't even have the code anymore that reflects this scenario.

Comment: Thanks anyway atconway.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the value TokenAccessLevels.MaximumAllowed as if it was the maximum privileges allowed, that means: as if it would give you all permissions...

...but that is not the case.

TokanAccesslevels.MaximumAllowed has a value of 0x02000000, which is the maximum value that thae enumeration can grow to at any time, a reference for future implementations.

Please, see [this page](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/principal/tokenaccesslevels.cs,97f98278efdac974) for the actual implementation of the enum.

For your code to work you need to set the desired access levels one by one via bitwise operations.

The code will certainly run if you substitute MAXIMUM_ALLOWED for

```
(uint)(TokenAccessLevels.Query | TokenAccessLevels.Duplicate | TokenAccessLevels.Impersonate)
```

in the PInvoke call for the DuplicateTokenEx function.

I know that you don't have the problem anymore, but that can help other people and, after all, you may run into the same problem again... ;)